# Access aws_autoscaling_group group created by aws_eks_node_group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

Once we create `aws_eks_node_group` resource in terraform, one autoscaling group is automatically created. I want to use the created one and modify it

I want to add **Maximum instance lifetime** inside autoscaling group

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get [name](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#name) of the ASG, and once you have the name you can get all further details of it using [aws_autoscaling_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/autoscaling_group) data source.

But you **can't modify** as data sources are immutable. You would have to use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) with AWS CLI to make any changes to it.

Usually you would use `scaling_config` to change settings of your `aws_eks_node_group` ASG.

Comment: I want to add Maximum instance lifetime inside autoscaling group. Is there any workaround? Dont think it can be done by scaling_config option

Comment: @AliMehdi No there is not, except local-exec, or performing full import of the auto-scaling group in some different tf configuration.

Comment: Thanks. If you can post some snippet in answer then it would be helpful